# Migrate legacy database users to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

We have an old PHP app in MySQL that we're currently rewriting in Rails and PostgreSQL.
I'm looking for a way to migrate users one-by-one when they first sign in to the new system, so that we migrate only active users.

Is there a hook in **Devise** that I can use to catch a failed login towards the new database and check if the user exists in the old MySQL database and migrate the user if found.

BTW, the Rails app can access both databases and the migration code is already in place that accepts old `username` as input.

Or should I just simply make a separate _migration_assistant_ page that accepts old logins and initiates the migration?

PS. any user can possibly have thousands of database records to migrate so it can take a bit of time, but we already make use of PosgreSQL's `COPY FROM` to speed it up (about a few secs per account).

**EDIT:**
There are currently about **5000** users and we expect roughly **1000** of them to return to the new site.

Comment: how many users? how many will return?

Comment: Added user counts to question

Comment: 5000 records is nothing for a database. I'd copy all the users over to the new DB, and add a field that let me track whether that user had returned and signed in. At some time in the future, if need-be, it would be simple to delete those who hadn't made the migration. It'd make the task a lot easier I think.

Comment: Are your old user database passwords encrypted?

Comment: @the Tin Man - there are 5000 users, each have thousands of records in other tables, together a bit less that half a million. While this still is nothing for a DB to handle day-to-day, it takes a while to migrate with indexes etc. But the main point is still to exclude **inactive** users from the migration. Sort of clean up if you will.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - not encrypted, but hashed, old DB uses MD5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could migrate the required data from just your users table.  Include the original primary key in a column 'old_id'.

Create a [custom encryptor](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-custom-encryptor) so that users can log in with their existing password.

[Redirect](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out) users when they log in to a page that triggers the migration process per user making use of the saved 'old_id'.

After your migration period you could look at the Devise [trackable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable) columns to determine which users can be cleaned up.